# Bootstrap dropdown at footer?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have issues with bootstrap dropdown in footer menu?

Here is example what am I talking about?

http://www.bootply.com/129846

Try to click on dropdown in footer, see what will happen, it will go under the page, and new scroll will appear?

Try to add dropdown to footer of page

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
     <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" id="drop5" class="dropdown-toggle">Dropdown 2 <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul aria-labelledby="drop5" role="menu" class="dropdown-menu" id="menu2">
                  <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Action</a></li>
                  <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Another action</a></li>
                  <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
                  <li role="presentation"><a href="#" tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just a quick question; why would you add a dropdown to a footer? A bit of topic, but seems to be creating unneccesary trouble.

Comment: add this class (.dropup) to dropdown

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu dropup" role="menu" aria-labelledby="labelname">
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this example](https://www.codemystery.com/try-it/try-bootstrap-dropup/) to be helpful. See code below.

```
            <div class="dropup">
                <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropup Example
                <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```